# Support for ES6 in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

According to this page http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, ES6 features are not implemented in IE 11.

Does IE 11 have a plan for implementing them one day or can I forget about it?
Is there a page that explain their intent on that subject?

I read somewhere (I cannot remember where exactly) that they don't plan to fix bugs in IE 11, so my guess is that they won't bother implement new features?

Comment: You can assume that the features in IE 11 are frozen and that only the Edge browser will get more features.

Comment: If you need to (or just want to) both use ES6 features and support IE11 and other old browsers, I'd recommend taking a look at a transplier such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

Comment: @t.niese Thanks. I wish I could just drop support for ie11, but that's just not the case, so you've got to do what you've got to do...

Comment: As @Frxstrem said you can still use many es6 features and then transpile your code and add polyfills if required.

Comment: Transpiling is ugly and adds an extra step. I also would like to use basic ES6 featurs in my code - it seems to be supported by all major browsers except for IE11. And to a bad surprise, they want to support IE11 till 2020 or even longer :(

Answer (score 48):

The [statement from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support) regarding the end of Internet Explorer 11 support mentions that it will continue to receive security updates, compatibility fixes, and technical support until its [end of life](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17454/lifecycle-faq-internet-explorer). The wording of this statement leads me to believe that Microsoft has no plans to continue adding features to Internet Explorer 11, and instead will be focusing on Edge.

If you require ES6 features in Internet Explorer 11, check out a transpiler such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

Comment: So which version does IE 11 support? Which ECMAScript version does this miserable program swallow? Just found it... ES 5 is what you would have to target... http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Comment: Notice also that even ES5 does not have 100% support on IE11. Microsoft's decision to keep IE on life support is really screwing ES over -- as suggested look into a transpiler like Babel or Typescript. Get it into your build process and stop worrying about IE ever again.

Comment: Gaud I was really hoping to overhaul all our old scripting at work, but IE just won't die fast enough! https://death-to-ie11.netlify.com/