# PDF.js not working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer-11, pdf.js

I've been looking for days now and I am still unable to get [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) working on IE11, regardless of IE11 is listed as a [supported browser](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#which-browsers-are-supported), as showed in [PDF.js DEMO](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html).

No errors are shown in Chrome's Console. However, there are 3 errors in IE11's Console:

[Chrome's Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KDr2.png)

[IE10's Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db2pE.png)

Could anyone provide some help? Thanks

Comment: `Promise` is not supported in IE11, you need to add [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill)

Answer (score 1):

IE11 doesn't support ES6 format, so some features of PDF.js won't work in IE11.

You could try to use the ES5 version of pdf.js and pdf.worker.js.

**Either :**

1. point **import "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"**  to  ***import "pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js"***
2. point **import "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js"** to => ***import "pdfjs- dist/es5/build/pdf.worker.js"***

**OR use ES5 version:**

1. **pdf.js** : https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/build/pdf.js
2. **pdf.worker.js**: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/build/pdf.worker.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because IE11 doesn't support ES6.
[Support for ES6 in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902809/support-for-es6-in-internet-explorer-11)

I hope this will help someone in the future.