# JS error in Internet Explorer - Expected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer

I'm getting the error 'Expected identifier' in Internet Explorer. Works in all other browsers.

```
                for(var [i, article] of articles.entries()) {
                  if(article.hero) {
                        heroes.unshift(article);
                        articles.splice(i, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: **Go to** [Destructuring assignment compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Destructuring is not supported in IE.

Comment: Go to [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility) also, this is also not supported

Comment: ...and [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Related: [Support for ES6 in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902809/support-for-es6-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: For..of loop is not supported in Internet Explorer. As an alternative, you can try to make a test with for..in loop or for loop may help your code to work in IE. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Support for ES6 in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902809/support-for-es6-in-internet-explorer-11)

Answer (score 0):

**Go to** [Destructuring assignment compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility)

Basically, the destructuring approach is not supported by IE, so you should modify your logic for a wider supported approach.

**For example:**

```
for (var i in articles) {
    var article = articles[i];
    if (article.hero) {
        heroes.unshift(article);
        articles.splice(i, 1); // (Pay attention) variable i should be a number.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for...of` is also not supported in IE

Comment: `entries` not support in IE

Comment: The entries() method not supporting in IE read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries

Answer (score 0):

Beow code should work:-

```
for (var _iterator = articles.entries(), _isArray = Array.isArray(_iterator), _i = 0, _iterator = _isArray ? _iterator : _iterator[Symbol.iterator]();;) {
  var _ref;

  if (_isArray) {
    if (_i >= _iterator.length) break;
    _ref = _iterator[_i++];
  } else {
    _i = _iterator.next();
    if (_i.done) break;
    _ref = _i.value;
  }

  var _ref2 = _ref,
      i = _ref2[0],
      article = _ref2[1];

  if (article.hero) {
    heroes.unshift(article);
    articles.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}
```

for conversion of javascript code
reference :- https://babeljs.io/repl

Answer (score 0):

Object and Array destructuring is not supported in IE. Neither is `Object.entries`.
Instead try using a normal `for` loop.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < articles.lenght; articles++) {
  var article = articles[i];
  if (article.hero) {
    heroes.unshift(article);
    articles.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}
```