# How can I make the following code work with IE

Tags: javascript, filepond

The following code is written with ES6:
How do I convert to pre ES6 so that its compatible with IE. I tried to following; see second code snipet below

```
FilePond.create(document.querySelector('input'), {
    acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png'],
    fileValidateTypeDetectType: (source, type) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // Do custom type detection here and return with promise

        resolve(type);
    })
});


i tried the following 

FilePond.create(imageInputElement, {
            acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/tiff', 'application/pdf'],
            fileValidateTypeDetectType: function (source, type) {
                                            return resolveFileType(resolve, reject);
                                        }
    })

async function resolveFileType(resolve, reject){
            const response = await resolve(type);
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for ES6 in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902809/support-for-es6-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: Use babel.js to transpile ES6.

Comment: i would prefer rewriting it to functions pre ES6 and replace promise with async function? but i need some help with that

Comment: Well what have you tried as far as converting? What doesn't work in your converted code? Can you show us your attempt at converting the above code?

Comment: i added what i tried

Comment: async / await is not supported in IE, you'll have to return a Promise. Which means you'll have to add a Promise polyfill as Promises are also not natively supported in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the online [transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) for `babel` or if you work in a complete project

with `ES6` so use task runner that will help you like [webpack, gulp]

or just fix your `promises` use a third party like `BlueBird` it uses to polyfill

promises in old browsers

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hmm i tried it thanks a lot! but it still uses a Promise which is not supported by IE

Comment: there is a third party called `bluebird` it use to polyfill the promises [link](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)